# data check function does not work

Tags: php, grocery-crud

I'm trying to check for a valid date in grocery crud (end date should be after start date) but the below code does not work it still saves the invalid date, can anyone help?

```
    $crud->set_rules('cardEnd','End Date','callback_valid_dates[cardEnd,cardStart]'); //dEnd before dStart
    $output = $this->grocery_crud->render();

    $output = $crud->render();
    $this->cards_output($output);


}


function cards_output($output = null)
{
    $this->load->view('cards_view.php', $output);
}

    public function check_dates($dEnd, $dStart)
{
    $var1 = explode('/', $this->input->post('dStart')); 

    $var2 = explode('/', $this->input->post('dEnd'));
    $dEnd = join('-', $var2);

    if ($dEnd >= $dStart)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('valid_date', "invalid date range end date must be after the start date ");
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `check_dates()` function with this-

```
public function check_dates($dEnd, $dStart)
{
    $var1 = strtotime($this->input->post('dStart')); 

    $var2 = strtotime($this->input->post('dEnd'));

    if ($var2 >= $var1)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('valid_date', "invalid date range end date must be after the start date ");
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, invalid dates are still allowed to be set, no idea why.

Comment: I have amended my code  and get the following error  Fatal error: Call to undefined function check_dates() in E:\EasyPHP\EasyPHP\data\localweb\wecan\application\controllers\main.php on line 257

Comment: my replacement code is currently being peer reviewed so might not show

Comment: $crud->set_rules('cardEnd','End Date',check_dates(['cardEnd', 'cardStart'])); 
  $output = $this->grocery_crud->render();

Comment: public function check_dates($cardEnd, $cardStart)
        {
    echo "function runs and starts";
    $var1 = strtotime($this->input->post('dStart')); 

    $var2 = strtotime($this->input->post('dEnd'));

    if ($var2 >= $var1)
    {
        echo "the function runs and value is TRUE";
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "the function runs and the value is False";
        $this->form_validation->set_message('valid_date', "invalid date range end date must be after the start date ");
        return FALSE;
            }
        }